# Reset Formik's dirty state to 'false' when a nullable value is changed to undefined

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using a fetch to populate the initial values for Formik. One of the fields is `null` in the fetch result (password).

When I use this in a field, and change the input field to a value, the dirty state of the form becomes true.

Then when I remove that value again Formik will stay 'dirty'. Since Formik makes the field 'undefined' and not 'null'.

Does someone have a workaround for this?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-cerf-29xw6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a value that is null, you get the following warning:

> Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.

So what you need to do is when you get the request, you have to set it to `''` when some prop is `null` / `undefined` .

Please notice that you can't have a `null` value and also can't have `undefined`, it will break the input handling.